# Could not find matching constructor Grails error

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have a User domain with a flag for security officer and a Location domain to hold all locations in my web app. I want to allow an administrator to assign a primary and secondary security officer to any location from a pick list of all users with the security officer flag checked. I have this working in a hand-made MVC structure, but I'm currently playing with scaffolding and have run into a strange error I can't figure out. My Location domain is coded as

```
class Location {

    static hasMany = [users:User] 

    Integer id
    ...
    String address
    String city
    State state
    String zip
    ...
    User primarySecurityOfficer
    User secondarySecurityOfficer

    static mapping = {
        table 'location'
        id generator: 'identity'
        sort "state"
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        ...
        address(blank: false, nullable: false)
        city(blank: false, nullable: false)
        state(blank: false, nullable: false)
        zip(blank: false, nullable: false, size: 5..5)
        ...
        primarySecurityOfficer(blank: true, nullable: true)
        secondarySecurityOfficer(blank: true, nullable: true)
    }
}
```

and I generated the views with `grails generate-all Location`. I modified the security officer selection in the generated `_form.gsp` to

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: locationInstance, field: 'primarySecurityOfficer', 'error')}">
  <label for="primarySecurityOfficer">
    <g:message code="location.primarySecurityOfficer.label" default="Primary Security Officer" />
  </label>
  <g:select id="primarySecurityOfficer" name="primarySecurityOfficer" value="${locationInstance?.primarySecurityOfficer?.employeeNumber}" from="${securityOfficers}" optionKey="employeeNumber" optionValue="${{it.firstName + ' ' + it.lastName}}" noSelection="${['null':' ']}" disabled="${disabled}"/>
</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: locationInstance, field: 'secondarySecurityOfficer', 'error')}">
  <label for="secondarySecurityOfficer">
    <g:message code="location.secondarySecurityOfficer.label" default="Secondary Security Officer" />
  </label>
  <g:select id="secondarySecurityOfficer" name="secondarySecurityOfficer" value="${locationInstance?.secondarySecurityOfficer?.employeeNumber}" from="${securityOfficers}" optionKey="employeeNumber" optionValue="${{it.firstName + ' ' + it.lastName}}" noSelection="${['null':' ']}" disabled="${disabled}"/>
</div>
```

and the controller's create and save auto-generated actions (modified to send the view the security officer list) are

```
def create() {
    def securityOfficers = User.findAll("from User as u where u.securityOfficer='1'")
    println params
    respond new Location(params), model: [ securityOfficers:securityOfficers ]
}

@Transactional
def save(Location locationInstance) {
    def securityOfficers = User.findAll("from User as u where u.securityOfficer='1'")

    if (locationInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (locationInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond locationInstance.errors, view:'create', model: [ securityOfficers: securityOfficers ]
        return
    }

    locationInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'locationInstance.label', default: 'Location'), locationInstance.id])
            redirect locationInstance
        }
        '*' { respond locationInstance, [status: CREATED], model: [ securityOfficers:securityOfficers ] }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is that if I select any security officers and try to save a new location, I get the error `Could not find matching constructor for: User(java.lang.String)`. If I leave the selector blank, the location will save successfully. Any ideas why?

Edit 1: Interesting find from tinkering around. I can successfully save security officers to locations if I change the view code to

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: locationInstance, field: 'primarySecurityOfficer', 'error')}">
  <label for="primarySecurityOfficer">
    <g:message code="location.primarySecurityOfficer.label" default="Primary Security Officer" />
  </label>
  <g:select id="primarySecurityOfficer.employeeNumber" name="primarySecurityOfficer.employeeNumber" value="${locationInstance?.primarySecurityOfficer?.employeeNumber}" from="${securityOfficers}" optionKey="employeeNumber" optionValue="${{it.firstName + ' ' + it.lastName}}" noSelection="${['null':' ']}" disabled="${disabled}"/>
</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: locationInstance, field: 'secondarySecurityOfficer', 'error')}">
  <label for="secondarySecurityOfficer">
    <g:message code="location.secondarySecurityOfficer.label" default="Secondary Security Officer" />
  </label>
  <g:select id="secondarySecurityOfficer.employeeNumber" name="secondarySecurityOfficer.employeeNumber" value="${locationInstance?.secondarySecurityOfficer?.employeeNumber}" from="${securityOfficers}" optionKey="employeeNumber" optionValue="${{it.firstName + ' ' + it.lastName}}" noSelection="${['null':' ']}" disabled="${disabled}"/>
</div>
```

But now I cannot save WITHOUT a security officer. The error I get if I attempt to is `Unparseable number: "null"`.

Comment: What if you changed your domain to:  String officerType, then in constraints create an inList: ['Primary Officer', 'Secondary Officer'], then go ahead and generate-all. The inList will generate the  _form.gsp with a drop down.

Comment: Could you please add User domain as well. Also, in second case when you select no value for security officer there goes null value which is not long. You may solve it by adding -1 in place of null in select box.